# Sort the List countries using JS/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, drop-down-menu

Hi I need the list of countries to be sorted so that France will be always on top of the list.

Below is the input order of the list.

```
<select id="countriesList" name="countriesListName">
  <option value="US">USA</option>
  <option value="DE">Germany</option>
  <option value="FR">France</option>
  <option value="DM">Denmark</option>
  <option value="">Choose Countries</option>
</select>
```

Comment: How do you want it sorted? shouldn't Denkmark be at the top if it is alphabetically ascending or USA if descending?

Comment: check [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/guradio/tw7j2rfj/)

Comment: You need to be more clear about what you want.  Do you want the list sorted alphabetically, but with France at the top, or do you simply want France moved to the top and don't care about the rest?

Comment: Just France to be in top and dont care about rest

Answer (score 4):

1. I sort the options
2. I move France to the top
3. I move the "Choose Coumtries" to top (perhaps not needed since its value is empty)
4. I select the "Choose Coumtries" // you can choose FR here

```js
$(function() {
  var $list = $("#countriesList"), $opts = $("option",$list);
  $opts.sort(function(a, b) {
    a = $(a).val();
    b = $(b).val();
    if (a > b) return 1;
    if (a < b) return -1;
    return 0;
  });
  $list.html($opts);
  // insertBefore or prepend
  $('option[value = "FR"]', $list).insertBefore($("option", $list).first());
  $('option[value = ""]', $list).insertBefore($("option", $list).first());
  $list.get(0).selectedIndex=0; // or 1 to select France
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="countriesList" name="countriesListName">
  <option value="US">USA</option>
  <option value="DE">Germany</option>
  <option value="FR">France</option>
  <option value="DM">Denmark</option>
  <option value="">Choose Countries</option>
</select>
```

Comment: i think explanation is needed?

Comment: Yes mate for experienced it is. but for OP i think it is not :) but you did explanation so i think OP will be good now :)

Comment: You could use `prependTo($list)` over `insertBefore()` with the additional selector, but good answer nonetheless.

Comment: I was looking for something like prepend @RoryMcCrossan - I forgot about it and settled on insertBefore since it is actually saying what we want to do

Answer (score 0):

Complete solution:

```js
$(function() {

  var options = $('#countriesList option');

  options.sort(function(a, b) {

    if (a.value > b.value) {

      return 1;
    }
    else if (a.value < b.value) {

      return -1;
    }
    else {

      return 0;
    }
  })

  $("#countriesList").empty().append(options);

  // Vive la France!

  $('#countriesList option[value="FR"]').insertAfter($('#countriesList option:first'));

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="countriesList" name="countriesListName">
  <option value="US">USA</option>
  <option value="DE">Germany</option>
  <option value="AZ">Azerbaijan</option>
  <option value="FR">France</option>
  <option value="DM">Denmark</option>
  <option value="">Choose Countries</option>
</select>
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

[Demo at sfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/r555yzxf/)

Comment: Why not use the snippet editor?

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction(country) {
    var select = document.getElementById("selectFrance");
    var opts = select.options.length;
    if ((select.options[1].value !== "FR")){
        for (var i=0; i<opts; i++){
            if (select.options[i].value == "FR"){
                select.insertBefore(select[i],select[1]); 
                break;
            }
        }
    }  
}
```